# PHP PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, pdo, drupal-8, utf8mb4

I have drupal 8 installed on Centos 6. 
Here is my php and mysql -version output

Server version: 5.7.9 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
PHP 5.6.14 (cli) (built: Oct 16 2015 08:41:09)

But i still getting a connection error

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/) in /var/www/m2m/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php on line 83

I also have this configuration on my OS X
Mysql Server version: 5.6.27 Homebrew
and PHP 5.6.15 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2015 07:39:39)

and everything is ok.

Do you have any idea?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you try `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` ? [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html)

Comment: Log in to MySQL and run `show character set like 'utf%';` , do you see utf8mb4?

Comment: mysql> show character set like 'utf%'
    -> ;
+---------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description      | Default collation  | Maxlen |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+--------+
| utf8    | UTF-8 Unicode    | utf8_general_ci    |      3 |
| utf8mb4 | UTF-8 Unicode    | utf8mb4_general_ci |      4 |
| utf16   | UTF-16 Unicode   | utf16_general_ci   |      4 |
| utf16le | UTF-16LE Unicode | utf16le_general_ci |      4 |

Comment: jumanji, i'm can't do this, because it should work from the box, and it works perfect on my OS X

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-initialize-character-set.html

Comment: a already have All extra charsets installed

Comment: The issue has been temporarily solved by adding a section with definition of utf8mb4 to my /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem on CentOS, all packages up-to-date. 
Issue was with the mysql driver. Fixed by running the following:

```
yum erase php56w-mysql
yum install php56w-mysqlnd
```

And restarting the webserver.