# Mysql2::Error Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, centos6, utf8mb4

In my Rails 4.2 app I stumbled on strange issue. I had to switch mysql encoding to utf8mb4 (to allow Emoji in posts).
I've updated MySql to 5.7, altered tabels etc. Updated database.yml with:

```
encoding: utf8mb4
collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Everything worked on my local machine that runs mac OS.

On test server I've done same steps and configuration. But if I set

```
encoding: utf8mb4
```

in database.yml
I get

```
Mysql2::Error Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)
```

Additional MySQL setup for mysql I've done in my.cnf on both machines:

```
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_large_prefix
innodb_file_per_table = 1

init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
innodb_file_format_max = Barracuda
innodb_strict_mode = 1

character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I can add emoji on test server but not through Rails app. 
On both machines I'm usign `mysql2` version `0.3.21`.
What can cause this issue?

PS. Even I don't have it on my local I've added utf8mb4 to Index.xml on test machine, but it didn't helped.

Comment: What is the MySQL Server version of your server? I think that is your problem. I believe utf8mb4 is supported since 5.5, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I use MySQL 5.7.19. Database itself supports uft8mb4 and I can insert symbols (emoji) to the database but not with Rails app.

Comment: @rolkos - see if this helps:  http://blog.arkency.com/2015/05/how-to-store-emoji-in-a-rails-app-with-a-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:  RoR: `application_controller.rb`:

```
  def configure_charsets
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    suppress(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
    end
  end
```

Comment: @rolkos - see if this helps:  http://blog.arkency.com/2015/05/how-to-store-emoji-in-a-rails-app-with-a-mysql-database/  Please let me know what specific steps you take to solve it.

Comment: I saw this article steps described there are similar to what I've done. Whats bother me is that it's working on local but not on test server with CentOS.

Comment: @rolkos - Run `SHOW VARIABLES;` on both machines; diff the results.  _Maybe_ something different will show up.  If possible, do that SHOW from within RoR, just in case, ROR is somehow causing a difference.

Comment: I've checked variables and there are no big difference, mainly performance settings. I noticed that when I run `rake c` I also get `Character set 'utf8mb4' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file` and then
`Mysql2::Error: Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-initialize-character-set.html  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834191/php-pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2019-cant-initialize-character-set-utf8mb4  https://www.drupal.org/node/2533424

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. It was as simple as updating mysql2 gem to 0.4.9, To make it work (updated mysql2 gem) I also had to update rails from 4.2.4 to 4.2.9. Now it works as a charm. But still, it's weird that on my mac it works with old gem. Rick, thank you for your help. In one of the links they mentioned about PHP adapter update, it pointed me to the right track.  Thanks.